# Can't understand Injective function from the test

Tags: functions

I had a test in classroom and I couldn't understand the solution of it.

The question is like this.

Assume that  $x\neq y\neq z\neq x$.

Is the function $f :\left \{x, y, z  \right \} \rightarrow  \left \{ 0, 1 \right \}$ defined by $f(x) = 0,$ $f(y) = 1,$ $f(z) = 0$ injective?

justify your answer.

So what I wrote is that

Since $f(x) = 0$ and $f(z) =0$ therefore not injective.

However I did not get the full mark so I checked the solution and it says

because $f(x) = 0 = f(z)$ and $x\neq z$ there for not injective.

I don't understand why the $x\neq z$ is so important in injective function and would it be injective if $x = z?$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, of course it would be injective if $x=z$. Injectivity means *distinct* elements of the domain map to distinct elements of the range. Just because we use different symbols $x$ and $z$ doesn't mean the elements they refer to are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Definiton of an injective function, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

An injective function or injection or one-to-one function is a function that preserves distinctness: it never maps **distinct** (this is the important catch) elements of its domain to the same element of its codomain.

---

As symplectomorphic stated in his comment, if $x=z$, then it would be injective because $x$ and $z$ are not distinct elements of the domain. Imagine that they are both equal to $2$, and $y$ is equal to $3$. Then $2$ maps to $0$ and $3$ maps to $1$. Since there are no elements in the domain that map to the same element in the codomain, it is an injective function.

Answer (score 1):

A function is *injective* when each element in the codomain is mapped to by *at most one* **distinct** element in the domain.   So, yes, the inequality is an important part of the counterexample; it witnesses the distinctness of $x,z$.

So in $f(x)=0=f(z)$ when $x\neq z$ you have a counterexample; an element in the codomain ($0$) which is mapped to by more than one distinct element in the domain (element $x$ and the *different* element $z$).

Answer (score 1):

It goes down on how to find an equivalent definition out of a given statement:

> **Definition 1.** Let $f:A\to B$ be a function. We say that $f$ is injective if $\forall a_1,a_2\in A$, we have
>   $$a_1\neq a_2\implies f(a_1)\neq f(a_2).$$

Equivalently,

> **Definition 2.** Let $f:A\to B$ be a function. We say that $f$ is not injective if $\exists a_1,a_2\in A$ for which 
>   $$a_1\neq a_2 \text{ and } f(a_1)= f(a_2).$$

---

In your question, we have $x,z$ are in the domain of $f$ but notice that 
$$x\neq z \text{ and } f(x)= 0=f(z).$$
Thus, using Definition 2, we conclude that $f$ is not injective.